# Best way to run through the entire sheet looking for a text in Google Sheets

Tags: replace, google-apps-script, google-sheets, find

I want to create a script that needs to find a certain string and replace it automatically. I've managed to do that, but it takes over 1 minute to run through all rows and columns to find it.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
for (i=1; i<=rows; i++) {
  for (j=1; j<=cols; j++)  {
    cell = content.getCell(i, j).getValue();
    if (content.getCell(i, j).getFormula()) {continue;}
    try {
      cell = cell.replace (find, replace);
      content.getCell(i, j).setValue(cell);
    }
    catch (err) {continue;}
  }
}
```

The built-in method replaces a text instantly, so I assume there is a better way to approach this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't see much difference between this approach and my first one, but it replaces all matches instantly now:

```
function findReplace() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var i, j, find, replace;
  find = "hello";
  replace = "bravo!!";  

  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { //Run through all rows
    for (j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) { //Run through all columns
      if (values[i][j] == find){
        values[i][j] = replace;
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: The difference here is the overhead introduced by making API Calls. Each time you use a function like getDataRange() or getCell() you are making an API call to the Google Spreadsheets API, each API call takes a non-trivial amount of time to complete.  So in this version you're using three API calls, getDataRange(), getValues(), setValues(), where as in the previous example you were making two or three API calls for each cell.

Comment: Mmmmh okay, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retrieving each cell from the sheet one by one, use getDataRange() and getValues() to get all of the data in an array in one call, then perform your search on the array.

Then, depending on if you might have live users editing at the same time your script is run or not, you can either replace the values within the array and re-write the entire sheet with setValues(), or you can use setValue() to update the specific cells with matches one by one as you are currently doing.

See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues

Comment: I was already using .getDataRange(), but looking at the documentation example helped me find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, I must have been looking at the code in Lazaro's answer when I wrote this

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
for (i=1; i<=rows; i++) {
  for (j=1; j<=cols; j++)  {
    cellLoc = content.getCell(i, j);
    cellValue = cellLoc.getValue();
    if (cellLoc.getFormula()) {continue;}
    try {
      cellValue = cellValue.replace (find, replace);
      cellLoc.setValue(cell);
    }
    catch (err) {continue;}
  }
}
```

I took off every instance of `content.getCell(i,j)` and instead stored it into cellLoc. That way every time you need `content.getCell(i,j)`, the program doesn't have to find the cell in the content, it can just look what the value of cellLoc is. Let me know if it works and if time has improved...

Comment: It has a better structure like this, but it still takes over a minute to run through all cells :/